# Cannot load a proprietary protocol because an implementation for java SPI is missing

Tags: java

Any help would be appreciated; I appologize foremost for my lack of proper terminology or context, but I am new to Java.  I have downloaded an SDK from a vendor which consists of an example application, which I cannot get to run.  This is the tomcat error which I am receiving below.

My thought was that jars are missing, but I cannot figure out which ones..

> 11-Aug-2010 18:02:02
>   com.avaya.conferencing.examples.acp.jsprosterdisplay.ACPConnectionContextListener
>   tryOpenConnection SEVERE: Context
>   [/acp-jsp-roster-display] Could not
>   establish connection to conferencing
>   provider smodapi://10.10.10.10 as
>   ******/****** java.net.MalformedURLException: Cannot
>   find an implementation supporting the
>   protocol smodapi  at
>   com.avaya.conferencing.api.acp.control.ConnectionContext.getConnection(ConnectionContext.java:282)
>     at
>   com.avaya.conferencing.api.acp.control.ConferencingProviders.getConnection(ConferencingProviders.java:84)
>     at
>   com.avaya.conferencing.examples.acp.jsprosterdisplay.ACPConnectionContextListener.tryOpenConnection(ACPConnectionContextListener.java:85)
>     at
>   com.avaya.conferencing.examples.acp.jsprosterdisplay.ACPConnectionContextListener.contextInitialized(ACPConnectionContextListener.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:905)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:740)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   11-Aug-2010 18:02:02
>   com.avaya.conferencing.examples.acp.jsprosterdisplay.ACPConnectionContextListener
>   contextInitialized INFO: Context
>   [/acp-jsp-roster-display] Startup
>   completed in 20ms.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone ever comes across the same error.  The app was missing the proprietary driver jar which was required to connect.  When compiling with Maven, be sure to insert the right .jar's into your repository!